# What are the advantages of Google fonts over cufon?

Tags: fonts, cufon

I am trying to work out whether I should use [Google fonts](http://code.google.com/webfonts?subset=latin) or [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/). Google fonts seem to be able to be copy/pasted and that is definitely an advantage. So I am leaning towards Google fonts.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, the link you provided for cufon was bogus. Took me to some ufo conspiracy site ;)

I think it's mostly preference of coding style. Cufon seems to be a tiny bit less strict on what browsers it's compatible with. But there's not a lot in it, google fonts covers probably 99% of the market share of browsers these days.

I have to say that google normally write some damn good documentation for things as well. So if you need the extra support. Google probably have it. Otherwise just choose the one you best like the look of.

Answer (score 0):

Go for Google fonts, simply because Cufon fonts are not readable by search engine bots, and would have an impact, if you are planning for an extended use.